# How to bind a StringProperty to a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `ChangeListener` that when triggered, a `findGPA()` method is called.

```
private void findGPA(){
    GPA = gradeCre/sum;
    decGPA = new BigDecimal(GPA);
    decGPA = decGPA.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    System.out.println("Your average GPA is: " + decGPA);
}
```

The `BigDecimal` is initialized as follows:

```
private BigDecimal decGPA = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

In the `initialize()` method:

```
SubmitStageBorderPane.setBottom(AddStackCircle());
```

which calls:

```
private StackPane AddStackCircle(){

    StackPane stackCircle = new StackPane();
    StringProperty gpa = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    gpa.bind(new SimpleStringProperty(decGPA.toString()));

    Text avgGPA = createText("Your semester GPA is: " + gpa);
    Circle resultCircle = createCircle(avgGPA);

    stackCircle.getStyleClass().add("stackCircle");
    stackCircle.getChildren().addAll(resultCircle, avgGPA);

    return stackCircle;
}

private Circle createCircle(Text avgGPA){

    Circle resultCircle = new Circle();
    resultCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    resultCircle.setStroke(Color.GREY);
    resultCircle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    resultCircle.setRadius(getWidth(avgGPA) / 2 + 10);

    return resultCircle;
}

private Text createText(String text){

    Text avgGPA = new Text(text);
    avgGPA.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
    avgGPA.getStyleClass().add("avgGPA");

    return avgGPA;
}
```

However, when i run it, it produces the following label text `Your semester GPA is: StringProperty[bound, invalid]`, and it doesn't change even when the value of  `decGPA` changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bidirectional bindings of different properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138082/bidirectional-bindings-of-different-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text to update, you'd need to bind the text of the `Text` node instead of simply setting the text. Furthermore you should bind it to a property that is actually updated, not just a property that will never be modidfied (like `new SimpleStringProperty(decGPA.toString())`).

Assuming the `findGPA` method is properly called, it should be implemented like this:

```
private final ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> decGPA = new SimpleObjectProperty(BigDecimal.ZERO);

private void findGPA(){
    GPA = gradeCre/sum;
    decGPA.set(BigDecimal.valueOf(GPA).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
    System.out.println("Your average GPA is: " + decGPA.get());
}

private Text createText(ObservableValue<String> textExpression){

    Text avgGPA = new Text();
    avgGPA.textProperty().bind(textExpression);
    avgGPA.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
    avgGPA.getStyleClass().add("avgGPA");

    return avgGPA;
}
```

```
Text avgGPA = createText(decGPA.asString("Your semester GPA is: %s"));
```